# Normal Vector to a Function in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

Let $r = f(\theta, \varphi)$ be a function defined in spherical coordinates, using the convention $x = r \sin \theta \cos \varphi$, $y = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi$, $z = r \cos \theta$. How can I compute the (inward or outward) normal vector on the surface defined by this function?

I tried looking at $G(r, \theta, \varphi) = r - f(\theta, \varphi)$ and computing $$\nabla G = \frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\vec e_r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial G}{\partial\theta}\vec e_\theta + \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial G}{\partial \varphi} \vec e_\varphi = \vec e_r - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\vec e_\theta - \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}\vec e_\varphi, $$
working analogously to the case that $z = f(x, y)$ has a normal vector $\vec n = \nabla (z-f(x, y))$, but this doesn't seem to work. I also looked at defining $\vec r = f(\theta, \varphi) \vec e_r$ but also couldn't see the next step from here as I'm unsure how to apply the cross product in this case to compute a normal.

Comment: Based on your definition $\nabla(z-f)=0$. Check your notes.

Comment: @K.defaoite What do you mean by this? I have it set equal to zero so that the surface is defined implicitly, using the fact that the gradient is normal to level curves, but the actual gradient is not zero.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say that computing the gradient of $r-f(\theta,\phi)$ didn't work?

Comment: @rpm2718 I tried with a specific example and converting into Cartesian coordinates and didn't get the same result (not proportional).

Comment: I think you were on the right track. I would suggest you scrutinize your calculation more, and be sure to plug back in $r=f(\theta,\phi)$ to your expression for $\nabla G$ if you haven't already.